# Virtualbox image to full install

Tags: virtualbox

I am new to Ubuntu, am using it via VirtualBox on Windows 7, and would like to potentially save an image of my VirtualBox setup and use it as my full install of the OS on the same machine. Is this doable?

Answer (score 4):

There used to be p2v and v2p tools for VBox images from Redhat, but they pulled support for them and the source disappeared from the interwebs.  I can't find a reference, but I assure you I found a project page with redacted/dead download areas at one point.

Evidently they decided to [endorse Acronis instead](http://www.redhat.com/resourcelibrary/reference-architectures/rhev-3-p-to-v-v-to-v-v-to-p-server-migration-using-acronis-backup-and-recovery).

There is also [vboot referenced here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=41746) which could do what you want sort of...in an easy way.

It's not a point-click process, but you can always:

1. uninstall guest additions
2. switch from a virt kernel to a generic kernel
3. dd guest partition to host partition
4. reconfigure grub
5. reconfigure graphics configs and other driver/interface naming
   related issues

Comment: Acronis has become teh suck since v10 (when it stopped being called True Image)...shame RH.

Answer (score 2):

Installing / reinstalling the system and software is not much of an issue. Your personal configurations are stored in general in your `/home` directory, so I would back up that, make a fresh Ubuntu install, and copy the `/home` backup to your new installation.